# Setting google map zoom level to 15

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps-api-3

I need help in this issue, please

I'm trying to set `Google Map` **zoom level** to **15**, but that cause the map not rendered completely, instead it rendered as gray area

this is a screenshot of the map to get what I mean

[image]

**And this is my code below**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var zoomLevel = 6;
        //(38.5923884129755, 31.0229229927063)39.86619, 35.44768
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5923884129755, 31.0229229927063);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: zoomLevel,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('GoogleMap_Div'), mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            addMarker(event.latLng);
        });

        var hdnZoom = $("input[id$='hdnZoom']")[0];
        var hdnLocation = $("input[id$='hdnLocation']")[0];
        if (hdnZoom && hdnLocation) {
            setMarker(hdnZoom.value, hdnLocation.value);
        }            
    }

    function setMarker(zoom, location) {

        if (zoom && zoom != '' && location && location != '') {

            var loc = location.split(",");
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[0].substring(1), loc[1].substring(0, (loc[1].length - 1)));
            if (latlng) {
                addMarker(latlng)
            }

            map.setZoom(parseInt(zoom)); //zoom = 15
        }
    }

    function addMarker(location) {
        clearOverlays();

        var hdnZoom = $("input[id$='hdnZoom']")[0];
        if (hdnZoom) {
            hdnZoom.value = map.getZoom();
        }

        var hdnLocation = $("input[id$='hdnLocation']")[0];
        if (hdnLocation) {
            hdnLocation.value = location;
        }

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map
        });

        markersArray.push(marker);
    }
```

this code work fine if the zoom level less than or equal to 8.

Comment: looks like you have a css issue with the way the map controls are messed up.

Comment: @geocodezip but it works fine in other cases, for example when I changed the latlng at "initialize()" function to var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5923884129755, 31.0229229927063); then I added a marker at the map using the following latlng latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5923884129755, 31.0229229927063); all that works fine, but if I set the zoom level to 15 after adding the marker the issue happened

Comment: WHat does your css and HTML look like?

Comment: [works fine for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_greyMap.html)

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you very much, the issue disappered when i removed other scripts were at the page :)

Answer (score 0):

the map not rendered completely is not caused by zoom level, check your latlng

Comment: I changed the latlng at "initialize()" function to 

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5923884129755, 31.0229229927063); 

then I added marker to the map using the following latlng 

latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.5923884129755, 31.0229229927063);

all that works fine, but when I'm trying to set the zoom level to 15 after adding the marker the issue happen

Comment: what I'm trying to do is to save the position of the marker that added by the user and the zooming level at the database, to add the marker to the map the next time the user visit the page and setting the map zoom level to the same level the user used when adding the marker